# Backups for online businesses - better external hard drives or tape drives

Tags: backup

We are an online business. Currently we are using DVD's for our backups. The problem is we are running out of space.

I guess there are two alternatives here:

- external hard disk drives
- tape drives

The important point is we want to carry the backup with us from the office to home every day.

Which alternative do you think would suit best our needs?

Answer (score 0):

> The important point is we want to
>   carry the backup with us from the
>   office to home every day.

This is on the level of "do we want to go to work or not". Backups that are not stored external ARE NOT BACKUPS. Ever heard of buildings going down? Burning out?

You NEED backups that are at least far enough to survive a larger fire.

Both scnearios are feasible. Tapes have more / larger capacity if you grow.

Also remember soonish we get... writeable 100gb Blue Ray discs ;)